# how to specify NULL as pointer-type argument to template function

Tags: c++

This shows the gist of it:

```
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
    A() { }
};

class B {
public:
    B() { }
};

typedef std::pair<A*, B*> ABPair;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B* b = 0;               // no C2440
    ABPair p2(new A(), b);

    ABPair p1(new A(), 0);  // C2440

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to make the p1 declaration work than just forcing a cast, e.g.
`ABPair p1(new A(), (B*)NULL)`?  This seems like it would be pretty common & that there would be a "right" way to do it .. and that casting it is not the right way.

On VS 2010, here's the full error:

```
1>ClCompile:
1>  test.cpp
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'B *'
1>          Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(247) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::_Pair_base<_Ty,int>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=A *,
1>              _Ty2=B *,
1>              _Ty=A *,
1>              _Other1=A *,
1>              _Other2=int
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\charliearnold\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\test\test\test.cpp(20) : see reference to function template instantiation 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair<A*,int>(_Other1 &&,_Other2 &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=A *,
1>              _Ty2=B *,
1>              _Other1=A *,
1>              _Other2=int
1>          ]
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(163): error C2439: 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second' : member could not be initialized
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=A *,
1>              _Ty2=B *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\utility(167) : see declaration of 'std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::second'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty1=A *,
1>              _Ty2=B *
1>          ]
1>
1>Build FAILED.
```

Comment: Your constructors don't match your object constructions. :)
I figure this is for simplification, but a testcase ought to compile aside from the asked-about error. Additionally, "C2440" is a vendor-specific error code so error text would be more useful.

Comment: OK, you've added the text now. :)

Comment: Why do you want to use 0 instead of NULL? This may not address the main point of your question, but isn't NULL much more readable in this case?

Comment: @Jonathan: http://jcatki.no-ip.org:8080/fncpp/NullOrZero

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not really. `nullptr` will fix this in C++0x, but for now, write `(B*)0`.

Comment: (You're not wrong to think that it's weird; that is why it is getting fixed :D)

Answer (score 5):

You could use the '`make_xxx()`' pattern:

```
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
    A() { }
};

class B {
public:
    B() { }
};

typedef std::pair<A*, B*> ABPair;

ABPair make_ABPair(A* pa, B* pb) 
{
    return ABPair(pa, pb);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    B* b = 0;               // no C2440
    ABPair p2(new A(), b);

    //ABPair p1(new A(), 0);  // C2440
    ABPair p1(make_ABPair(new A(), 0));

    return 0;
}
```

This will let you pass not only 0, but anything that's implicitly convertible to to an `A*` or `B*`.

Comment: Good thinking. A little more verbose than `(B*)0` but arguably neater nonetheless.

Comment: I'm confused, why does MSVC allow the conversion from `int` to `B*` as an argument to `make_ABPair`, but not as an argument to the constructor of ABPair? GCC accepts the questioner's code with `-pedantic`, as does Comeau. Is this a breaking change in C++0x that MSVC already supports?

Comment: @Steve he's using a c++0x enabled library which has a perfect forwarding constructor. So it really calls a `pair(A*&&, int&&)` constructor, trying to initialize the `B*` data member using the `int` parameter.

Comment: @Steve: It's potentially a huge breaking change in C++0x that MSVC already supports, yes.

Comment: @Tomalak ah NVM. It says just after the "Requires: ..." paragraph: "Remarks: If U is not implicitly convertible to first_type or V is not implicitly convertible to second_type this constructor shall not participate in overload resolution.". So this just looks like a MSVC++ lib bug.