# Give nullptr a type for template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, nullptr

Suppose the following snippet:

```
template <class T>
void fct(T* a, T* b){
  // do something
}

A a;
fct(&a, nullptr); // Problem here!
```

This makes trouble, since the call arguments are of type `A*` and `nullptr_t` and so the compiler can not deduce template parameter `T`.

Generally, I can imagine several ideas how to solve this:

- Define `A* b = nullptr` and use `fct(&a, b)`
- Define an overload with one argument for `fct` for the `nullptr` case
- Use `fct(&a, static_cast<A*>(nullptr))`

**Or is there a more clean solution, like the creation of a something like a "typed nullptr"?**

Comment: How your wanted "typed nullptr" could be different from `static_cast<A*>(nullptr)`?

Comment: your 2nd alternative looks like the best bet...overload(template specialization)

Comment: You already answered in question... 1st and 3rd alternatives are more or less the same: you need a T* and nullptr is not so you disallow `fct(&a, nullptr)`, and 2nd uses an explicit overload to allow it. I cannot imagine another answer...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633971/unable-to-pass-null-function-pointer-as-template-argument pretty much same dilemma

Comment: Did you try explicit instantiation? ```fct<A>(&a, nullptr);```

Comment: My suggestions would be to answer these two questions: 1. Is the solution readable? And 2. Does it make sense in your model / environment / structure? So, each of the so far provided solutions may be implemented with maximum readability. And whether it makes sense is your decision.

Answer (score 7):

Just make the second argument a non-deduced context, e.g:

```
template <class T>
void fct(T* a, std::remove_reference<T*>::type b) {
```

Comment: missing `typename` in front of the second function argument? One could also use the newer and slightly less verbose`std::remove_reference_t`.

Comment: With C++20 you can use `std::type_identity`: `void fct(T* a, std::type_identity_t<T*> b)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest the following solution:

```
template <class T, class U>
void fct(T* a, U b){
  T* b2 = b;
  // do something
}

A a;
fct(&a, nullptr);
```

This allows for a wider usage of `fct`, but maybe that's exactly what you want to.

For example, consider

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

...
A a;
B b;
fct(&a, &b); // calls fct<A>
// the following will not compile:
// fct(&b, &a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void f_impl(T*, T*)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\n";
}


template<class T, class U>
void f(T l, U r)
{
    static_assert((std::is_same<T, U>::value && std::is_pointer<T>::value) || 
                  (std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value && std::is_pointer<U>::value) || // First non-null 
                  (std::is_same<U, std::nullptr_t>::value && std::is_pointer<T>::value)    // Second non-null
                  , "");

    using P = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, std::nullptr_t>::value, U, T>::type; 

    f_impl<typename std::remove_pointer<P>::type>(l, r);
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    f(&i, nullptr);
    f(nullptr, &i);
    // f(i, nullptr); // won't compile - non-pointer
    f(&i, &i);

    double d;
    // f(&i, &d); // - won't compile

}
```

This version tests will allow to call `f` with one `nullptr` (but not both), or with two pointers to the same type. With c++14 you can also use things like `std::conditional_t`, `std::remove_pointer_t` and `std::is_null_pointer` to remove some biolerplate.

Comment: You need to call `f<T>` or `f<U>` depending on which is non-null; your current version calls `f<nullptr_t>` when invoked as `f(nullptr, &i)`.

Comment: @Petr There were more problems with that code. Fixed them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As the question already states, `nullptr` in fact has a type: `std::nullptr_t`. So just add an explicit overload for specifically that case:

```
template <class T>
void fct(T* a, std::nullptr_t b) { return fct<T>(a,static_cast<T*>(b)); }
```

No need to have some template argument `class U` for that.